# Ansible ad-hoc command with an included name, comment, or description of the action?

Tags: logging, ansible, administration, audit-logging

Using ansible with logging enabled is useful for auditing the history of actions taken on a server. I argue it is also important to indicate *why* a specific changes is made.

In *playbooks*, I can use the `name` keyword to describe what a change is and why it is done. However, I need help finding a way to include a description of actions taken when running ansible via *ad-hoc commands*.

Ideally, there would be a `--name` option, then I could do this:

```
ansible webservers -a "shutdown -r now" --name "Restarting webservers to load updated kernels"
```

Or perhaps, if I could run two ad-hoc commands at once, I could include a debug msg:

```
ansible webservers -a "shutdown -r now" -m debug -a "msg='Restarting webservers to load updated kernels'"
```

Is there any way to have a comment logged by ansible when running an ad-hoc command?

---

Edit: I just realize the specific commands executed ad-hoc aren't logged, e.g., running `ansible -v all -a "date"` prints the output of `date` to the log, but not the command itself:

```
2022-05-15 14:20:23,991 p=67807 u=q n=ansible | 1.2.3.4 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
Sun 15 May 2022 07:20:23 PM UTC
```

Any way to get ansible to log the command itself that is run?

Answer (score 2):

There is no possibility to pass a name to an ad-hoc command, and, this way of running Ansible is meant for a single module to be run, so, no, you won't be able to add a debug message in.

This said, in your specific use case, you could probably use the optional [`wall`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wall.1.html) message that `shutdown` allow you to add in order to have an indication of the reason why those nodes where rebooted:

```sh
ansible webservers \
  -a "shutdown -r now 'Restarting webservers to load updated kernels'"
```

Comment: Thanks, your reply gave me an idea: I can use the shell module and include an echo statement to print a comment to the logs: `ansible webservers -m shell -a "echo 'Restarting webservers to load updated kernels'; shutdown -r now"`.